# App optimization on every reboot?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, updates, optimization

I received the official OTA Google update to Android Ice Cream Sandwich 4.0.3 on my HTC Sensation. Every time now when I reboot the device, the system displays a notice stating that it is optimizing the installed apps. This should be just on the first reboot after the update and not every time?

Answer (score 3):

This seems like it may be a bug in the update that HTC has released for their phones. [It's been reported on the Android issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=27658) and appears to affect various HTC models only. You can star the issue if you want, and some people have suggested that enabling the "Fast Boot" option in your settings may help (something like `Settings->Power`, I believe). On other devices it should only run at first boot or when the Dalvik cache has been erased.

If it's of interest, the details regarding what the optimization is actually doing have been covered in [What kind of app optimizations do newer Android versions do at the first reboot?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/21653/what-kind-of-app-optimization-does-ice-cream-sandwich-do-at-the-first-reboot)

Answer (score 2):

This issue has now been fixed in a recent OTA update.  This updated the HTC Software version (*NOT* Sense) to **V3.33.401.6**. Applying the upgrade removes the issue.

This is further corroborated by other users previously experiencing the same problem: [1](http://androidforums.com/htc-sensation/576689-ota-update-3-33-401-6-a.html#post4620388), [2](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=27658#c67), [3](http://androidforums.com/htc-sensation/576689-ota-update-3-33-401-6-a.html#post4633120), [4](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=27658#c54).

Took them long enough!

Answer (score -1):

In general, the "application optimisation", which I assume is JIT compilation of all the installed APKs, should only happened once during the first boot (and probably also during the first boot after flashing.)

Why it is running every time, I do not know. Sounds like an error.

Comment: That's hardly JIT, is it? :P

Comment: @MatthewRead: Actually, as far as I understand I is really the JIT process being performed during the first boot. I know that contradicts the term JIT (a bit). See the sources that eldarerathis provides, they confirm this.