# Lollipop/ART - how do I manually optimize APK files?

Tags: stock-android, customization, system-apps, art, odex

I've asked [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/157846/126804) before. After checking out `logcat`, it seems that the OS is looking for the `odex` files. I've checked the `odex` files of other system apps on my ROM, and it turns out they're `ELF` files.

For the ones asking, these are bytecode files produced by ART (`dex2oat`, I'm not sure).

I've observed that these files get generated on boot (`Android is Starting: Optimizing App XXX of XXX`).

For some reason, my phone's ROM doesn't run the optimization part. Instead, the `oat` files are already pre-generated and stored on the system partition. As a result, the apps that I want to pre-install don't get the `oat` treatment and crashes when I launch them (`ClassNotFoundException` since the `oat` files don't exist.)

**How do I manually run the app optimizer?** If it comes down to using the command line, how do I use `dex2oat` **without root access/on a Linux PC**?

Comment: **[How to Odex apk Files directly using your android phone](http://andro-ids.blogspot.in/2015/05/how-to-re-odex-apk-files-directly-using.html)**

Comment: Try a Google search. "How to run app optimization process Android" should do already.

Comment: @Namnodorel It doesn't, unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but have a look over here: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/139655/how-to-re-run-the-app-optimization-process-after-upgrading-to-a-higher-version